# Is it a sank ship please see near japan

Tags: satellite, google, mapping

I found this photo on google map satellite mode looks like sank ship[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is not a ship that sank. It is a result of how the background image is made up of a large number of images that are combined.
Google uses a multitemporal approach to creating their basemap and this method works well in most areas, but does result in ships appearing as sunken or "ghostly".